# Possible to use DI in Java form?

Tags: java, forms, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I'm using the form exactly as described here in the documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms

In my java form I use dependency-injection.
In my controller I inject the FormFactory and create the form.
In my view.scala.html I use the form as described in the documentation.

But the view gives me the following error:

```
[RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate class models.User. It must have a default constructor]
```

**Is dependency injection possible for java forms in play?**

Example java form:

```
public class User {

    @Required
    protected String email;

    private final EmailValidator validator;

    @Inject
    public User(EmailValidator validator){
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = validator.parse(email);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

Example controller:

```
public class FormController extends Controller {

    private final Form<User> userForm;

    @Inject
    public FormController(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.userForm = formFactory.form(User.class);
    }

    public Result loadForm() {
        return ok(userFormView.render(userForm));
    }

}
```

Example view.scala.html:

```
@(userForm: Form[User])

@helper.form(routes.RegistrationController.register()) {
    @helper.inputText(userForm("email"))
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

Comment: I don't think its possible. You should check https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Advanced-validation how to implement your own validators in forms. Either implement your own validation annotation or use Play's `Validatable` interface

Comment: @AlexanderB I'm actually using play's validation. The code above was just a short example to show my problem. Using play's validation doesn't change anything about the problem of not being able to inject a dependency. I still would need to inject the dependency.

Comment: Actually the documentation states how to create a constraint/validator with DI support, so e.g if you want to look up emails in the DB for duplicates you should be able to do that: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Custom-class-level-constraints-with-DI-support.

Comment: @AlexanderB Thank you for the hint. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexanderB I did implement the DI support as described in the documentation and this somewhat works. The thing is, this only adds DI to the validate method and not to the model class. Also you need min. 3 helper classes to archive this. It's not a beautiful solution.

Comment: I agree, it requires lots of boilerplate code. However I would argument that not having any dependencies in your model is a good thing :-)